# half animal has a mirror. Can I move the tail from one side to the other?

Tags: modeling

I have modeled with a mirror. Now I want to do the tail. The tail has to move from one side to the other but I can't because half animal has a mirror. [image]

When I try to move the tail from one side to the other, this is the result.[image]

Is it possible?  Can I take off the mirror just in the tail?

Comment: Is this for an animation? Also, this is happening because of Clipping is checked, means once vertexes connect to another one, they will stay together until clipping is unchecked.

Comment: Thanks @Luka ash  for your answer. I am leaning to modeling  before animation. I will do it like you said. Thanks

Comment: Thanks @Mr. Zak for your answer. I will folow your instructions. Thanks

Comment: @Mr Zak.  I did it but when I cliked mirror again half of the tail appaer, I mean I don't want to have two tails. How can I do it?

Comment: @Luka ash. when I diconnect Clipping two tails appear. I want to do a circle with one tail. How can I do it? Thanks

Comment: Provided that this is Mirror modifier it will mirror every part of the mesh. If you'd like to position part of that object somehow you need to do that after modeling and applying Mirror in order to have all parts of mesh accessible for independent editing.

Comment: Try selecting the tail in edit mode, hit P with the faces selected then go into object mode, select the tail and apply the mirror modifier, then back into edit mode and you should be good to go, if that's what "Can I take off the mirror just in the tail?" means.

Comment: If you're trying to create a pose for the animal (where the tail is not in the center) **this should be done in Pose Mode** after you've rigged it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another alternative is to keep the mesh symmetric with the tail in the center, and then add an Armature with bones to control the tail and then pose the armature to make the tail off-center.

The order of the modifiers (mirror and armature) are probably important.

Edit: [image] is a .blend file illustrating the technique and proving that it is possible to pose a mirrored mesh without applying the mirror modifier (leaving it as a modifier).

Comment: No. You have to apply the mofifier first.
Make a copy before you do it.